# Получить данные из объекта

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

В Laravel, через `$text = DB::table('articles')->select('text')->get();` получил переменную с результатом  `                 Object (

```
                    [items:protected] => 

                    Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [text] => Vestibulum. ) ) 

                    )`
```

И текст выводится таким образом

> [{"text":"Vestibulum ."}]

Итак, вопрос, как обратиться к объекту, чтобы получить текст? И ещё один необязательный вопрос, зачем Laravel стоит объекты с трёхэтажными массивами, чтобы передать просто текст?

Comment: `$text = DB::table('articles')->select('text')->get()->toArray();`

Comment: Выдал массив с объектом, тоже непонятно как добраться до текста. 'Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [text] => Vestibulum . ) )' @robertobadjo

Comment: `$text[0] -> text;`

Comment: "Узнать все" про объект, метод, функцию в PHP поможет Reflection API. В вашем случает это [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.construct.php). Откройте для себя Reflection, и перестанете искать по коду.

Answer (score 1):

> И ещё один необязательный вопрос, зачем Laravel стоит объекты с трёхэтажными массивами, чтобы передать просто текст?

Что вы у него просите, то он и строит, читайте документацию.

Если хотите получить только значение используйте метод `value` если нужно одно значение:

```
$text = DB::table('articles')->value('text'); // строка
```

Или если нужен массив всех значений используйте `pluck`:

```
$text = DB::table('articles')->pluck('text')->toArray(); // массив строк.
```

Answer (score 0):

не советую писать на laravel DB::... лутше писать Eloquent-ом стандарт laravel но  если так то get() возврашает object и на view надо делать так вот пример

```
 @foreach ($db as $item)
   {{$item['name']}} //елементи DB 
    {{$item['email']}}
  @endforeach
{{}}->обратиться к объекту
```

Comment: Чем DB так плох?

Comment: нет не плох просто у laravel есть есть стандарты с ними код зделают быстрее лутше писать Eloquent-ом https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent